# Async method MVS AJAX WCF not async?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, async-await

I'm having a problem using an async wcf method frome my serverside called by ajax method.
Here is the client side code:

```
        var options = {
            'url': '/Home/MyControllerMethod',
            'data': {
                p1: p1,
                p2: p2,
                p3: lbl.GetValue(),
                //ville: Ville.GetValue(),
                //adresse: Adresse.GetValue()                
            }
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (liste) { 
        //do stuff 
        });
```

Here is my multiple tests for controller side code:

Test 1

```
    public ActionResult MyControllerMethod(string p1= null, string p2 = null, string p3= null, string p4= null)
    {
      var wcfClientChannel = UtilsDAO.GetMyWCF();
      var liste = wcfClientChannel.MyWCFGetListAsync(p1, "", p2, "");
      return Json(liste, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Test 2

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyControllerMethod(string p1= null, string p2 = null, string p3= null, string p4= null)
        {
          var wcfClientChannel = UtilsDAO.GetMyWCF();
          var liste = await wcfClientChannel.MyWCFGetListAsync(p1, "", p2, "");
          return Json(liste, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Test 2

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyControllerMethod(string p1= null, string p2 = null, string p3= null, string p4= null)
        {
          var wcfClientChannel = UtilsDAO.GetMyWCF();
          var liste = await wcfClientChannel.MyWCFGetListAsync(p1, "", p2, "").ConfigureAwait(false);
          return Json(liste, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

MyWCFGetListAsync take 15sec to get values.
All my tests are "working" but not as i'm expecting.
My problem is that all other ajax calls/method are waiting that MyControllerMethod() has finished.

I'm probably missing something but i don't understand two things:

- why is my ajax is not executing asynchronously?
- why my method is locking the thread while he waits for results in test 2 and Test 3?

Comment: Have you tried using promise. That is javascript new feature for async calls.

Comment: This is usually due to session state on ASP.NET, or an equivalent concept on WCF.